# Imprimir árbol binario, en su forma de árbol

Tags: java, estructuras-de-datos, árboles-binarios

Tengo el siguiente problema necesito imprimir el árbol binario(montículo máximo), en su forma de árbol(vertical).
He intentado con un recorrido en amplitud(BFS). Pero si tengo el siguiente árbol:

102 101 103 50 99 31 200

```
     200
     / \
   102  103
   / \   / \
  50 31 99 100
```

Este este caso este árbol cumple la propiedad de montículo binario máximo.
Con un recorrido (BfS), la salida seria:

```
200 102 103 50 31 99 100
```

Esta es su forma horizontal, ahora bien lo que busco es poder mostrarlo en una manera de árbol, de la siguiente manera:

```
200
102 103
50 31 99 100
```

Recomendaciones y sugerencias son bienvenidas.

**Recorrido BFS**

```
public int BFS(node p_tree) {
    if (p_tree == null) {
        return 1;
    }
    Queue<node> queue_level = new LinkedList<>();
    queue_level.clear();
    queue_level.add(p_tree);
    while (!(queue_level.isEmpty())) {
        node temp = queue_level.remove();
        System.out.print(temp.getKey_value() + " ");
        if (temp.getP_left() != null) {
            queue_level.add(temp.getP_left());
        }
        if (temp.getP_rigth() != null) {
            queue_level.add(temp.getP_rigth());
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Podrias usar esta clase, te lo imprime en forma de árbol con las ramitas.

```
public class TreePrinter{
    public interface PrintableNode{
    PrintableNode getIzquierdo();
    PrintableNode getDerecho();

}

public static void print(PrintableNode root)
{
    List<List<String>> lines = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

    List<PrintableNode> level = new ArrayList<PrintableNode>();
    List<PrintableNode> next = new ArrayList<PrintableNode>();

    level.add(root);
    int nn = 1;

    int widest = 0;

    while (nn != 0) {
        List<String> line = new ArrayList<String>();

        nn = 0;

        for (PrintableNode n : level) {
            if (n == null) {
                line.add(null);

                next.add(null);
                next.add(null);
            } else {
                String aa = n.toString();
                line.add(aa);
                if (aa.length() > widest) widest = aa.length();

                next.add(n.getIzquierdo());
                next.add(n.getDerecho());

                if (n.getIzquierdo() != null) nn++;
                if (n.getDerecho() != null) nn++;
            }
        }

        if (widest % 2 == 1) widest++;

        lines.add(line);

        List<PrintableNode> tmp = level;
        level = next;
        next = tmp;
        next.clear();
    }

    int perpiece = lines.get(lines.size() - 1).size() * (widest + 4);
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
        List<String> line = lines.get(i);
        int hpw = (int) Math.floor(perpiece / 2f) - 1;

        if (i > 0) {
            for (int j = 0; j < line.size(); j++) {

                // split node
                char c = ' ';
                if (j % 2 == 1) {
                    if (line.get(j - 1) != null) {
                        c = (line.get(j) != null) ? '┴' : '┘';
                    } else {
                        if (j < line.size() && line.get(j) != null) c = '└';
                    }
                }
                System.out.print(c);

                // lines and spaces
                if (line.get(j) == null) {
                    for (int k = 0; k < perpiece - 1; k++) {
                        System.out.print(" ");
                    }
                } else {

                    for (int k = 0; k < hpw; k++) {
                        System.out.print(j % 2 == 0 ? " " : "─");
                    }
                    System.out.print(j % 2 == 0 ? "┌" : "┐");
                    for (int k = 0; k < hpw; k++) {
                        System.out.print(j % 2 == 0 ? "─" : " ");
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        // print line of numbers
        for (int j = 0; j < line.size(); j++) {

            String f = line.get(j);
            if (f == null) f = "";
            int gap1 = (int) Math.ceil(perpiece / 2f - f.length() / 2f);
            int gap2 = (int) Math.floor(perpiece / 2f - f.length() / 2f);

            // a number
            for (int k = 0; k < gap1; k++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.print(f);
            for (int k = 0; k < gap2; k++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();

        perpiece /= 2;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Quizás sería bueno agregar una pequeña descripción de cómo lo hace (además de qué hace). El enlace para [edit] está al pie de tu respuesta.